# React-Chartjs-2 - How to make the label text stayed center wrapped?

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I need the text in this graph to stay center wrapped but it goes horizontal instead. Had anyone had this issue with chartjs?

[Picture of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzNVj.png)

It works if you used a set amount of letters such as 'dummy'.

```
  datasets: {
    labels: ["Dummy text 1", "Dummy text 2", "Dummy text 3"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "",
        data: [13, 11, 2],
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(0, 135, 136)",
          "rgba(0, 193, 189)",
          "rgba(255, 9, 49)"
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(0, 135, 136)",
          "rgba(0, 193, 189)",
          "rgba(255, 9, 49)"
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this easily with a multi-array and changing the xaxes. Here's the example fix -

```
  labels: [
  ["Dummy", "Data 1"],
  ["Dummy", "Data 2"],
  ["Dummy", "Data 3"]
],

 xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            maxRotation: 0,
            minRotation: 0
          },
      }
  ]
```

Hopefully this helps someone out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        callback: function (label, index, labels) {
          if (/\s/.test(label)) {
            return label.split(' ');
          } else {
            return label;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

This callback function will split your X Axis labels on the basis of space and arrange all the words in a wrapped manner. You can use the same function for Y axis values as well

Comment: This callback function will split your X Axis labels on the basis of space and arrange all the words in a wrapped manner. You can use the same function for Y axis values as well.